# set Interval function giving output for previous parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

```js
function callme(a) {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("fetch a" + a);
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="callme(1)">call 1</button>
<button onclick="callme(0)">call 0</button>
```

when 'call 1' button click output is

```
fetch 1
fetch 1
fetch 1
.
.
fetch 1
```

but when 'call 0' button click output becomes

```
fetch 1
fetch 0
fetch 1
fetch 0
fetch 1
.
.
```

how to stop previous loop execution ??

---

i want output like

when 'call 1' clicked

```
fetch 1
fetch 1
fetch 1
.
.
```

when 'call 0' clicked

```
fetch 0
fetch 0
fetch 0
.
.
```

Comment: You should have a clear interval on every new click or before call

Comment: Save the interval ref and clear it.

Comment: `let tId;
    function callme(a) {
      clearInterval(tId);
      tId = setInterval(function() {
        console.log("fetch a" + a);
      }, 2000);
    }
`